# SQL syntax error were am i goign wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys and girls im trying to a sql update but think i forgot a ' or a "
im getting this error messege

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Brock'='1'WHERE username = 'admin'' at line 1

The fault lies with in this bit of code if i take the code out the page loads witht he rest of the scripts on it. But need it two do the update.

```
$blah = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET '".$_SESSION['gymleader']."'='1'WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Were am i going wrong ?

Comment: You have a column named Brock?.... love your hard-coding! It'll cause you loads of problems in the future. Column names aren't strings to be quoted using ' If they do need quoting because they're reserved words, then you use backticks `

Comment: the error message points you directly to your error. See Robin's answer for more information and read carefully what the computer says and what you type :)

Comment: Wow. I think it would help to see the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that this looks like a bad idea to code like this, assuming you have a column named Brock then you should use this types of quotes instead:

```
$blah = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `".$_SESSION['gymleader']."`='1' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Notice I replaced your `'` with `` ` ``

Comment: Thanks for getting to the point and not taking the mick like others about the `

Comment: @nute, Stackoverflow uses backquotes to mark up code - this is also achieved by indenting, which then leaves the backquotes unaffected. I have amended your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You miss a space between the '1' and the `WHERE` if I am not mistaken. And you should use backticks (`) when you want to escape a column name

So your code becomes:

```
$blah = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `".$_SESSION['gymleader']."`='1' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

Note the ` instead of the ' around the column name (right after the `SET`).

Further possible improvements:

1. In case the column is of type INT, you can replace the `'1'` by `1` (without the ')
2. You should never directly use the `$_SESSION`,`$_POST`,`$_GET` or other values which can be altered by users in your queries. Do a Google search on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for more information

Comment: Have you also taken care of the comment of Mark Baker (the use backticks around your column names, and only when needed) ?

Comment: No i don't know what he is on about please explain ?

Comment: I updated my answer and included some of the comments made by others in it. Hopefully you understand it now

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE user SET field = '1' WHERE ...
```

instead of

```
UPDATE user SET 'field' = '1' WHERE ...
```

and if your field is of type int, you might use

```
UPDATE user SET field = 1 WHERE
```

If you want to escape your fieldname, use

```
`field`
```

in backticks `

Comment: I want to change were you have "field " into a session virable  $_SESSION['gymleader']  im getting ''Brock' = 1 WHERE username = 'admin''      if you notice there are 2  '' in front of the word brock maybe that is the problem ?

Comment: that would be mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ".$_SESSION['gymleader']." = '1' WHE...